# An issue with 3D CSS in Safari

Tags: html, css, 3d

I'm trying to create a rotating 3d box in CSS. The box is located on the vertical panel.

The CSS works well in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari, the faces are messed up at the end of the round. The front gray part "jumps" in a strange way.

CodePen with an example can be found here:
https://codepen.io/jsoceandiver/pen/RwKEWbO

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

I tried to remove the transform-origin property, and still, there is an issue:
https://codepen.io/jsoceandiver/pen/JjEwXJy

**Edit #2**

I found the issue - it was perspective property on the HTML tag. Once I removed it, the problem disappeared. Fixed codepen is here - https://codepen.io/jsoceandiver/pen/PoWXzOZ

```css
html, body{ 
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    perspective: 2000px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.panel{
    border: 1px solid #111;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    animation: rotation 5s infinite linear;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes rotation {
    100% { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
}

.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.box-part{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.box-part__front{
  background: gray;
  transform: translateZ(50px);
}

.box-part__back{
  transform: translateZ(-50px);
  background: red;
}

.box-part__left{
  transform: translateZ(50px) rotateY(-270deg);
  background: yellow;
}

.box-part__right{
    left: 100%;
    transform: translateZ(50px) rotateY(90deg);
    background: blue;
}

.box-part box-part__top{
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    background: #000;
}

.box-part box-part__bottom{
    top: 100%;
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="box">
      <div class="box-part box-part__back"></div>
      <div class="box-part box-part__front"></div>
      <div class="box-part box-part__left"></div>
      <div class="box-part box-part__right"></div>
      <div class="box-part box-part__top"></div>
      <div class="box-part box-part__bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: i believe the problem is the transform-origin...try to set transform-box as well see more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box

Comment: I tried it now, and unfortunately it doesn't work - https://codepen.io/jsoceandiver/pen/jOyXqyN
I tried content-box, border-box and fill-box in different places.

Answer (score 0):

Removing perspective property from the HTML tag fixes the issue.

For example, the following code:

```css
html, body{
    perspective: 2000px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Should be changed to:

```css
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body{
  perspective: 2000px;
}
```

Working codepen is here:
https://codepen.io/jsoceandiver/pen/PoWXzOZ